# Guys, who can help accept member in discord py

Tags: python, discord.py

Code:

```
channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
for m in channel.members:
        print(m)
```

I get an error - `discord.ext.commands.errors.MemberNotFound: Member "<@&821955352711004170>" not found.`.
What I must do?

Comment: use ``` not ''' when adding a code

Comment: Note that the style we aim for here is authoritative -- think of this like a FAQ, not a forum; it's better to be informative (and as terse as possible while communicating all the needed information) than conversational.

Answer (score 0):

May it be possible that this member is a bot and it doesn‘t work due to this? Never mind, you can use try & except I guess:

```
channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
for member in channel.members:
    try:
        # you should use str() to let the member be printed out like member#1234
        print(str(member))
    except:
        continue
```